# Excel Taskpane Addin update after published

Tags: excel-addins

We are developing a React Excel Taskpane Addin. Lets say that we have publish it and users have added the Addin in their Excel. If we deliver an update how does the Addin gets updated? Is it pulled by Excel without user intervention?

We have gone through Microsoft documentation.